# The best way to judge is (to get/get) - which is correct?

Tags: infinitives, to-infinitive

1. The best way to judge is get a boat and fill the boat with it.
2. The best way to judge is to get ...

Which one is correct, get or to get?

Comment: Either one is correct .

Comment: Thank you. But why is your opinion different from Mathias?

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence is correct. You need the infinitive form (*to* + verb) because a naked verb is not an appropriate object for *is*; a noun or adjective is required. The infinitive form of verbs can function grammatically as a noun, representing the abstract activity of the verb. And that's the case here, because the sentence refers to the idea of acquiring and filling a boat.

You may hear the version without *to* in spoken, informal English. Omitting prepositions or other "minor" trappings of grammar is common in colloquial speech.

> The best way to do is get/to get a boat.... Would you say 'get' is correct in this case? What's the difference? Why judge with to get, but do with get?

It's the same here; use the version with *to*. However, you also need to add a direct object for *do*: *the best way to do **it** is to get...*

Answer (score -2):

The second sentence

> The best way to judge is to get a boat and fill the boat with it.

is correct.

Comment: Thank you. How about in this sentence? The best way to do is get/to get a boat.... Would you say 'get' is correct in this case? What's the difference? Why judge with to get, but do with get?